# How to set focus to textfields in custom directive used inside 'editableCellTemplate'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm having a custom directive in `editableCellTemplate` and whenever I select the text the cell gets selected and when I press "F2" or double click this cell it shows up the custom directive but the textfield inside the directive does not gain focus.

How can I set focus into the textfield inside the custom directive?

Look at the 'Gender' column in [this fiddle](http://embed.plnkr.co/eSFIxVBuYk4JBq2HXMqG/). The 'TAB' and 'SHIFT + TAB'sequence is not working properly look at the inconsistency in gaining focus to the text field under the 'Gender' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this using events such as focus and blur.

See the solution [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sXSSzgkNpYOWOFJHS7q6?p=preview).

```
myApp.directive('focusComponent', ['uiGridConstants', 'uiGridEditConstants',
  function(uiGridConstants, uiGridEditConstants) {
    return {
      require: ['?^uiGrid', '?^uiGridRenderContainer'],
      scope: true,
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div><div>Some text</div><input type="text"></div>',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
        console.log(element);
        console.log(arguments);
        setTimeout(function() {
          angular.element($(element).children().children()[1])[0].focus();
          angular.element($(element).children().children()[1])[0].select();
        }, 10);

        var uiGridCtrl = controllers[0];
        var renderContainerCtrl = controllers[1];

        //set focus at start of edit
        $scope.$on(uiGridEditConstants.events.BEGIN_CELL_EDIT, function() {
          var thisEle = angular.element($(element).children().children()[1])[0];
          thisEle.focus();
          thisEle.select();
          thisEle.style.width = (thisEle.parentElement.offsetWidth - 1) + 'px';
          element.on('blur', function(evt) {
            console.log("blur - element");
            $scope.stopEdit(evt);
          });
        });


        $scope.stopEdit = function(evt) {
          // no need to validate a dropdown - invalid values shouldn't be
          // available in the list
          $scope.$emit(uiGridEditConstants.events.END_CELL_EDIT);
        };

        element.on('keydown', function(evt) {
          switch (evt.keyCode) {
            case uiGridConstants.keymap.ESC:
              evt.stopPropagation();
              $scope.$emit(uiGridEditConstants.events.CANCEL_CELL_EDIT);
              break;
          }
          if (uiGridCtrl && uiGridCtrl.grid.api.cellNav) {
            evt.uiGridTargetRenderContainerId = renderContainerCtrl.containerId;
            if (uiGridCtrl.cellNav.handleKeyDown(evt) !== null) {
              $scope.stopEdit(evt);
            }
          } else {
            //handle enter and tab for editing not using cellNav
            switch (evt.keyCode) {
              case uiGridConstants.keymap.ENTER: // Enter (Leave Field)
              case uiGridConstants.keymap.TAB:
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();
                $scope.stopEdit(evt);
                break;
            }
          }
          return true;
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public setFocus(el: string): any {
    var vm = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + el).focus();
        $("#" + el).select();

    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: The question is regarding an AngularJS plugin called UI Grid. How is your answer relevant?